# Finite group made up of two categories, all objects sampled without replacement into groups of size n, probability of at least x from first category

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Using Hypergeometric Probability Distribution function, I can calculate the probability of *exactly* x from first category ending up in groups of size n. But how do I calculate *at least* x from first category?

Edit: Is it just function for exactly 3 + function for exactly 4?

**Example of *exactly* x**

To calculate probability of exactly x from first category ending up in groups of size n, the numerator is categoryOneSize choose x, times categoryTwoSize choose n-x, and the denominator is N choose n. N is population size, n is the group size. Using group size = 4, population = 100, category one = 20 and category two = 80, and x = 3, 20c3 * 80c1/100c4 = 2.3%. Expected value 4*20/100 = 0.8 from category one per group.

I wrote a script to test for result. It gives expected result for *exactly* x, and a slightly higher result for *at least* x. How is *at least x* calculated mathematically?

```
# cook your dish here

import math
import random

N = 1000000
categoryOne = int(N/5)
n = 4
registry = [0]*N

for i in range(N):
    registry[i] = i

for i in range(N):
    randomNumber = random.randint(i, N-1)
    registry[i], registry[randomNumber] = registry[randomNumber], registry[i]

counter = 0
x = 0
success = 0
for i in range(N):
    if registry[i] < categoryOne: x += 1
    counter+=1
    if counter == n:
        if x == 3:
            success+=1
        x = 0
        counter = 0
print(success/(N/n)*100, "%", sep="")
```

Comment: To calculate $P(X\ge x)$, the best you can do is to add up the probabilities of exactly getting all values which are $x$ or greater, i.e. $P(X=x)+P(X=x+1)+\dots+P(X=n)$. There is no nice formula.

Comment: Hi thanks I just realized that, just before your comment. From this site, https://www.real-statistics.com/binomial-and-related-distributions/hypergeometric-distribution/. Fits perfectly with my test results. Awesome, thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case no one else answers this, what ME wrote in comment was

> To calculate (≥), the best you can do is to add up the
> probabilities of exactly getting all values which are  or greater,
> i.e. (=)+(=+1)+⋯+(=). There is no nice formula.

That fits my test results, and works. So, I'll put that as an answer here in case no one else does.